# Is there a way to detect reload:true in controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

On a click, I'm forcing the reload of a state. I was wondering if it was possible to catch that event in the controller? My view being made of two sub-views, I need one of the sub-views to initialise its values.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like the ui-route exposes this information.  Here's an idea though.  Listen to the $stateChangeSuccess event (or $stateChangeStart depending on your situation).  In this event, you could compare toState and toParams to fromState and fromParams, to deduce that this was a reload.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (angular.equals(toState, fromState) && angular.equals(toParams, fromParams)) {
            console.log('reload');
        }
        else {
            console.log('not a reload');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: This only works if it's doing a strict reload. Not if there's a page navigation with a reload which unfortunately I'm trying to track. Any ideas here? `@state.go 'home', {}, { reload: true }`